# C++ reverse_iterator error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, vector, reverse-iterator

I am trying to use a reverse_iterator for my vector and apparently this line of code is causing 3 errors.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<string> list={};
vector<string> reverse_iterator rit = list.rbegin();
```

Errors:

1. Expected a ';'
2. Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'rit'
3. Error   C2065   'rit': undeclared identifier

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Console Application.

Comment: Try `vector<string>::reverse_iterator rit = list.rbegin();`.

Comment: This is a very good place to use the type-deducing features introduced in C++11: `auto rit = list.rbegin();`

Comment: @songyuanyao it printed 25 more errors when I added the two colons

Comment: For help with those errors, maybe you can tell us what `list` is? Is the code you show *complete*? It doesn't really look like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Your answer solved it.

Comment: By the way be careful when having `using namespace std;` and using generic names such as `list`. Remember that there is a `std::list` class, so if you include `<list>` you will have a naming conflict. Also, calling a vector `list` is kind of misleading, isn't it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the tip. I am still new to coding in C++ and calling it a list for me is not really misleading. As long as I understand what it does, well I will call it a list. I put lots of comments for my team to look what each one does so I don't get anyone asking me what each one does.

Comment: std::list is reserved class in C++ so you can't use it as variable name

Comment: @MohammadOghli: No, you just don't use `using namespace std`, then you can use `list` without any problem.

Comment: @MohammadOghli and other people concerned with the list class. I have NOT included the list header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define your vector variable first :

```
std::vector<string> mylist (5);
```

then use a reverse_iterator for it :

```
std::vector<string>::reverse_iterator rit = mylist.rbegin();
```

**update:**

if you put `using namespace std;` then when you compile your code

you will find that the problem with `list={}`

because `list` is **reserved** class in `namespace std` so you can't use it as variable name when you define `vector`.

to solve the problem you can simply give it another name like `mylist`.

**Another way:**

if you don't put `using namespace std;`

no problem with declaring your vector as `list`

you can do it in this way and it will compile and work as you expected:

```
  std::vector<std::string> list={};
  std::vector<std::string>::reverse_iterator rit = list.rbegin();
```

I hope this will help you solve your error.

Comment: `std::list` is "reserved" just like anything else in `std`. That's one of the reasons why you do not use `using namespace std;`. Remove the `using namespace std;` and `list` is fine.

Comment: @ChristianHackl you are right thanks for the note I have updated my answer vote for it if you find it useful